# Cannot use opengl multismapling on Jupyerhub

Tags: opengl, graphics, jupyter-notebook, driver, glfw

I am trying to run a project that uses multi-sampling, but the output is not multi-sampled (Not getting any errors)

What I am doing:

```
...
glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 32)
...
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)
...
```

Mult-sampling works when I try to run it locally.

GPU on JupyterHub:
*VGA compatible controller: Cirrus Logic GD 5446*

Is there any way I can get the multi-sampling to work on Jupyter?

Comment: "Cirrus Logic GD 5446" isn't a GPU, this is a 25 year old PCI graphics chip that is emulated on the VM architecturer JupyterHub uses, and it won't do any hardware rendering whatsoever.  So you most likely end up with [mesa](https://mesa3d.org/)'s _software renderer_, and that _simply does not implement multisampling_ (It only [false-advertises itself as multisampling-capable](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/blob/205e737f51baf2958c047ae6ce3af66bffb52b37/docs/features.txt#L69) to fulfill OpenGL 3.0 requirements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as mentioned in the comments, it is an emulation on vm that Jupyter uses, so hardware rendering is not possible.